# Inline module script (Laravel webpack)

Tags: laravel, webpack, module, inline

I am trying to run a javascript module inline. I can't figure out how.
I am using Laravel and Webpack. I am not so technical, I just follow the docs as much as possible.

resources/assets/js/revision.js

```
var revision = function () {
    console.log('Hell world');
};

module.exports = revision;
```

I run npm run dev with this webpack.mix.js

```
mix.js('resources/assets/revision.js', 'public/js/revision.js').version();
```

I have tried [this url](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-es6-modules/#usinges6modulesinbrowsers)

```
<script type="module">
        import { revision } from '/js/revision.js';
</script>
```

gives "The requested module '/js/revision.js' does not provide an export named 'revision'"

and

```
<script type="module" src="{{ asset('js/revision.js') }}"></script>
```

is not doing anything....

Comment: `resources/assets/js/revision.js` vs `'resources/assets/revision.js'`

Comment: export should be module.exports instead of module.export for commonjs module

Comment: @Indragith good point, it was a typo, updated it